# Insert blank blob data in oracle using c

Tags: c, oracle

I am trying to insert blank data in blob column of table using C program in oracle database but it is inserting as Null, How to make it blank instead of null.data type is lpBlob.

Comment: define `blank` - short answer, fill your blob with 0x20 (that's spaces)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your definition of "blank", my assumption is that you want to use the `empty_blob` function

```
INSERT INTO table_name( ..., blob_column_name )
  VALUES( ..., empty_blob() );
```

Comment: I am not using sql, I am inserting the data using C program

Comment: @user1773207 - Presumably, your C application is issuing SQL statements (either directly or via some client API).  If you want to insert an empty BLOB, you'd need to use the `empty_blob` function.

Comment: I tried to fill blob with blank but still it is inserting null in oracle, Is there any function in C like java to insert empty blob.

Comment: @user1773207 - What API are you using?  OCI?  OCCI?  Something else?  Can you edit your question to include the code that you're using?

Comment: I am using OCI API, same code is working for other database(SQL server /DB2) but for oracle database it is inserting as NULL in blob field.

Comment: I am using OCI API, same code is working for other database(SQL server /DB2) but for oracle database it is inserting as NULL in blob field.    What I think is for oracle database we can't insert like that, we need to pass EMPTY_BLOB() function and I tried that also but it is also inserting NULL. I found in OCI API OCIBindByName function is passing EMPTY_BLOB() but its length is 0 as I gave the size of blob is 0, Here is my code:                                               retcode = (int) OCIStmtExecute( svchp, stmtp, errhp, iters, rowoff,
422     snap_in, snap_out, mode);

Comment: @user1773207 - OCI is an Oracle-specific API.  You can't work with a SQL Server or a DB2 database using OCI.  You can only connect to and work with an Oracle database.  So I'm rather confused about the statement that the "same code" is working against other databases.

Comment: Ok please leave that, How I should insert blank blob in oracle using OCI, it is my structure of blob in C:     struct blob{  void * lpvalue  ; int lsize}

Comment: one Alternative is to create temp blob then it will create empty blob